# Open GL ES tutorials

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hello firstly sorry for asking like this. I want to know about openGL ES in android is there any detailed tutorials. I google it but i found some of them with direct projects but i need to know from basic level can any one help me with this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have trouble finding what you seem to be looking for. Implementation of the openGL is quite hard and there are a lot of things that can go wrong. Most people that are trying to learn it will want to be able to draw at least something in the first day of learning so details on the setup to begin with are usually left out or discussed later in the tutorial.

You may be able to find some books that have details on pretty much anything so you may search for those. Still those are quickly outdated and a combination of tutorials, examples and solutions such as those on SO are more appropriate in most cases.

So when you are reading a tutorial it is awesome if you already have a project with it as you may start changing things around and see what the results are. You should not try to understand every line as you go if you are a beginner but rather focus on what you are interested in.

Still when you are looking at some examples you should not take them too seriously. The code structure is usually far from manageable and the examples are truly meant as examples and maybe something you can play with.

You will see the main parts you generally need for openGL are a context and a buffer. I think you get both quite out of the box in Android and you may setup most of the things with initializing a surface. You will usually find a default or most common setup which you should use until you find a specific problem which may be fixed by changing those.

To continue on ES2 (trust me not to go to ES1) you will need to create some programs (shaders) and compile them. If you want to add some images you will need to look into textures. Then for a nice 3D cube you will most likely need some matrices to create a nice projection. If for instance you want to draw a cube which has an image on each face and is rotating around you may quickly come to 1000 lines of code or more.

This does not mean you will need so much code for everything you want to draw but it means openGL is very flexible and it is up to you to design your tools. So getting a texture from image should be in a separate class which is constructed with image name and has a public method to bind the texture and to delete it; then this class will be complete until you get to use FBO. A shader should be wrapped in a class again and like the image it is best initialized with some source files so you may actually code them (some just put the source string in the code), then again expose all the methods you may need. A cube can be in some "model" class which can then include the vertex data or buffers and may have extra data such as location, rotation or simply a model matrix...

So once you come to this point in your application you will be able to see a bigger picture on how things work and start looking for detailed answers and solutions. But first rather just download the examples, read tutorials and keep playing around with the code.

I may add that I have never seen a good tutorial for openGL but then again I have never written it either. The reason for that is that it is simply too big to structure it nicely for someone that needs a tutorial. So we should still be thankful for these tutorials and examples and respect the people that have written them, trimmed them down so much that you may easily read through the code. I hopes this clears the question of "is there any detailed tutorials".

Comment: Whew!Thanks man for the valuable suggestion